# Limit of $a_n = \sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having some difficulties with this limit calculation:

I need to find the limit of the sequence $a_n = \sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)}$.

Intuitively, for large $n$ and since the sine function is bounded, we have that

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)} \sim \sqrt[n]{2^n} = (2^n)^{1/n} = 2$$

but I need to show this rigorously.

I also thought of taking an upper bound for the sine function, that is

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)} \leq \sqrt[n]{2^n+1}$$

but it but it doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: What about a lower bound?

Comment: Beware in maths, $\sim$ does not mean ‘approximately equal to ’!

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I used the symbol $\sim$ to note that for large $n$, the sequence $\sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)}$ behaves like $\sqrt[n]{2^n}$. Is this notation appropriate here?

Comment: @Elix He was probably referring here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition Which asserts your limit by definition of '$\sim$'

Comment: $~$ is used for asymptotic equivalence of functions or sequences (roughly, their ratio tends to $1$ at infinity). This symbol is subject to very precise rules which you did not respect. You should have used $\approx$ (LaTeX  command: `\approx`, precisely).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the squeeze theorem: observe that
$$2^{n-1}\leq 2^n-1\leq 2^n+\sin(n)\leq 2^n+1\leq 2^{n+1} $$
since $-1\leq \sin(n)\leq 1$, and
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n-1}{n}}=2=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$

Comment: XD we do some good fast service.  +1 for the exact answer I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{2^n+\sin(n)}=2(1+\frac{\sin n}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
we know that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$
$$1+\frac{\sin n}{2^n}<n$$
so 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{\sin n}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$
so the limit of sequence  is $2$

Comment: Hm, I think you showed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sin n}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}\le1$, not that it is actually equal.

Comment: @SimpleArt $ I think that the comparison is very clear

Comment: Thank you for posting this second alternative to solve the exercise. There is one point in your demonstration that I don't understand: how did you get the inequality $1+\frac{\sin n}{2^n}<n$?

Comment: @Elix I think that you can easly check this inequality when $n$ very large